# How to start/stop Glassfish 2.1.1 with Java Service Wrapper?

Tags: java, glassfish

I'm trying to install Glassfish 2.1.1 as a Service on a Windows server.

I followed this article without any luck:

http://www.ryandelaplante.com/2009/08/in-past-i-have-chosen-to-use-commercial.html

Has anyone been able to install Glassfish 2.1.1 as a Windows Service using Tanuki Java Service Wrapper ?

http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Project Kenai to run Glassfish 3.0 as a service.  I don't see any reason that it wouldn't work for 2.1.1.  http://projectkenai.com/projects/winsw/pages/Home

Comment: Glassfish 3.0 actually generates the exe and needed files when you ask for it with the create-service command.  It is winsw, and it - sigh - requires .NET.

Comment: @Thorbjørn  Good to know!  Wondering why I've never run across "create-service" anywhere in the docs or online though?  Where'd you find out about it?

Comment: I tried project Kenai on Windows 7 Professional. It worked correctly to install Glassfish 2.1.1 as a Windows Service. Glassfish 2.1.1 started when starting to service but failed to stop when stopping the service.

I finally made it work using the following command line:
C:\windows\system32\sc.exe create GlassfishV2 binPath= "C:\Sun\glassfish\lib\appservService.exe \"C:\Sun\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat start-domain domain1\" \"C:\Sun\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat
stop-domain domain1\"" start= auto DisplayName= "GlassfishV2"